# Prepending 1d array onto each 2d array of a 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have the size `(2,3,2)` array `a` and the size `(2)` array b below.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]])
b = np.array([0.2, 0.8])
```

Array `a` looks like this:

[image: array a]

I'd like to use numpy routines to concatenate `b` to the first row of each 2d arrray in `a` to make the array

[image: b array]

I can't seem to make `concatenate`, `vstack`, `append`, etc. work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
np.concatenate(([[b]]*2,a),axis=1)
# Result:
array([[[  0.2,   0.8],
        [  1. ,   2. ],
        [  3. ,   4. ],
        [  5. ,   6. ]],

       [[  0.2,   0.8],
        [  7. ,   8. ],
        [  9. ,  10. ],
        [ 11. ,  12. ]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
np.insert(a.astype(float), 0, b, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[  0.2,   0.8],
        [  1. ,   2. ],
        [  3. ,   4. ],
        [  5. ,   6. ]],

       [[  0.2,   0.8],
        [  7. ,   8. ],
        [  9. ,  10. ],
        [ 11. ,  12. ]]])
```

If you don't cast with `astype()` first, you just end up prepending `[0, 0]`

Note, this is slower than the `concatenate()`:

```
$ python test.py
m1: 8.20246601105 sec
m2: 43.8010189533 sec
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import timeit

a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]])
b = np.array([0.2, 0.8])

def m1():
    np.concatenate(([[b]]*2,a),axis=1)

def m2():
    np.insert(a.astype(float), 0, b, 1)

print "m1: %s sec" % timeit.timeit(m1)
print "m2: %s sec"  % timeit.timeit(m2)
```